# ¿Porque el tamaño de una imagen codificada en base64 es diferente al original?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy usando el API de ficheros de javascript para leer imágenes usando el método [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) y me topé con que mis imágenes siempre eran más grandes que sus originales, en un caso incluso 1 MB más grande.

Este es el código que estoy usando

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#source').on('change', function(evt) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      $('#encoded').text('El tamaño codificado es ' + reader.result.length / 1024 + ' kb')
    }

    if (file) {
      $('#original').text('El tamaño original es ' + file.size / 1024 + ' kb')
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="source" type="file">
<div id="original"></div>
<div id="encoded"></div>
```

No sé si es que se me está escapando algo aquí o existe alguna razón para este comportamiento. Alguien sabe cuál puede ser la causa?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Base64 es una representación en caracteres imprimibles de un contenido binario.** Para que sea imprimible, Base64 usa un alfabeto de 64 caracteres, 6 bits por caracter.

El "desperdicio" aparece por que Base64 se almacena/transporta en bytes (como todo lo demás), por ello para cada byte que almacenas en representación Base64 necesitas 1 byte + 2 bits del siguiente byte de almacenamiento.. disco, red, memoria, etc.

Un diagrama dice mas que mil palabras:

```
 byte    | base 64
-------- + ---------------------------
 1 byte  | 1 byte + 2 bits.
 2 byte  | 2 byte + 4 bits.
 3 byte  | 3 byte + 6 bits = 4 bytes (recuerda, solo 6 bits)
```

Es decir que cada bloque de 3 bytes del archivo original se convierte en 4 bytes en formato Base64, por ello eso como mínimo el tamaño aumentara en una relación 4/3, es decir el 133%. A ello le deberás sumar el relleno (no siempre los tamaños de los archivos serán múltiplos de 3) y los retornos de carro que halla en el archivo de transferencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta detallada!! Sabía que habrían variaciones en los tamaños al codificarlos pero me llamó la atención que el patrón era que siempre crecían y siempre con aproximadamente la misma proporción.

Answer (score 5):

Acabo de probar con una imagen de los siguientes tamaños:

- Size: 16.8 KB (17.276 bytes)
- Size on disk: 20.0 KB (20.480 bytes).

Haciendo uso de tu ejemplo, me resulta:

- El tamaño original es 16.87109375 kb.
- El tamaño codificado es 22.517578125 kb.

Vamos a la San Wikipedia en inglés https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

> Thus, the actual length of MIME-compliant Base64-encoded binary data
>   is usually about 137% of the original data length, though for very
>   short messages the overhead can be much higher due to the overhead of
>   the headers.

Y en la San Wikipedia en español https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

> MIME no especifica un tamaño fijo para las líneas codificadas en
>   base64, pero sí precisa un tamaño máximo de 76 caracteres. Además,
>   concreta que cualquier carácter que no pertenezca al alfabeto deberá
>   ser ignorado por los decodificadores, aunque muchas implementaciones
>   usan los caracteres CR/LF (retorno de carro y salto de línea) para
>   delimitar las líneas codificadas. De esta manera, el tamaño real de
>   los datos codificados conforme a MIME suele ser de un 140% del tamaño
>   original.

Sea 137% o 140%, el tamaño aumentará al utilizar Base64. Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

FileReader transforma la imagen a en una cadena de texto en base64:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA8Q1JF...
```

Mientras que tu variabe `file` es un objeto de tipo `File` que contiene la imagen **en binario**.

Para más información del objeto `File` puedes leer [esta documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)