# App android con indexedb ocupa mas espacio en el dispositivo del que debería

Tags: javascript, html5, indexeddb, phonegap

Estoy aprendiendo a programar apps con html5, css y javascript, que después compilo con phonegap. 
Estoy haciendo pruebas e instalándolas en el móvil. La app lo que hace es importar una imagen usando un ’ input type–file’, esta la asigno en un elemento ‘img’ con la propiedad ‘src’. Después se almacena en una tabla de una ‘base de datos’ creada con indexedDB, asociada a un número.
Después las recupero para asociarlas con otros elementos ‘img’, como si fueran imágenes de perfil de usuarios.

Lo he probado en el móvil android y me funciona, por lo que creo que no hay problema de compatibilidad pero he revisado en ‘ajustes-aplicacion-app.instalada’, para ver cuanto ocupa. Y me he dado cuenta, que por cada imagen que almaceno los datos almacenados aumentan 10MB. Por ejemplo cuando la imagen solo ocupa 1MB y después de cambiar varias imágenes el volumen de MB aumenta exageradamente, más teniendo en cuenta que después de asignar imagen a cada elemento lo que hago es reemplazar las imágenes y no añadir.

> También me he dado cuenta que después de seleccionar la imagen la ‘pinta’ bastante rápido, pero después en el proceso de almacenarla y recuperarla va muy lento.

```js
function startDB(pestana){
dataBase=indexedDB.open("generacion2",1);//conecta con la base de datos indicada.

//esta crea nueva base de datos creada o una nueva version
dataBase.onupgradeneeded=function (e){   
 var active=dataBase.result;//recupera el resultado de conectar la base de datos.
 opciones={//creamos un objeto que pasamos despues en el segundo argumento al crear el almacen de objetos
  keyPath:"id", //clave primaria indexada autoincremental
  autoIncrement:true
 };    
 var almacen= active.createObjectStore("marcos",opciones); //crea un almacen de objetos
 almacen.createIndex("num_marco","marco",{unique:true});  //crea una clave , se pueden crear varias
 //num_marco es un indice que se crea en base a la propiedad marco
 primeraVez='0';
 localStorage.setItem("primeraVez",primeraVez);                          
 
};


dataBase.onsuccess=function (e){
 if(primeraVez==='0'){                               
  primeraVez='1';
  localStorage.setItem("primeraVez",primeraVez);                               
  tablaOriginal();
 }
 
};

dataBase.onerror=function (e){
 alert("error al cargar la base de datos");
};

}
//función llamada cuando se crea la base de datos por primera vez, para cargar la imagen por defecto.
function tablaOriginal(){
var active = dataBase.result;
var datos = active.transaction(['marcos'], 'readwrite');
var carga_almacen = datos.objectStore("marcos");
//insertar items
alert('tabla iniciada');
for (var i=1;i<17;i++){
 var respuesta=carga_almacen.put({
  marco:i,
  imagenes:"img/logo.png",
 });
 
 respuesta.onerror=function(e){
  alert(respuesta.error.name+"\n\n"+respuesta.error.message);
 };
 
 respuesta.oncomplete=function (e){
  alert("object successfully added");
 };
};
}

//modificar imagen
//selecciona y carga la imagen          
function copiarURL(input) {
numCargar=numeroDeMarco;//le asigna el numero de marco a cambiar que lo uso como indice.

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function (e) {
  imagen=reader.result;//guardo la imagen
  
  //cambio la imagen guardada por la nueva
  var numero=parseInt(numCargar);
  var active = dataBase.result;
  var datos = active.transaction(['marcos'], 'readwrite');
  var carga_almacen = datos.objectStore("marcos");
  var index = carga_almacen.index("num_marco");//ordena por el keypath num_marco, para buscar segun el numero de marco                         
  var respuesta=index.get(numero);//obtengo el registro a cambiar.
  
  respuesta.onsuccess=function(e){
   var temp=respuesta.result;
   temp.imagenes=imagen;//le asigno la imagen guardada con el imput-file
   
   var actualizar=carga_almacen.put(temp);
   actualizar.onerror=function(e){alert('error al cargar actualizar');};                             
   actualizar.onsuccess=function(e){
    
    leerDBconf();//llama a funcion que vuelve a leer la base de datos ya modificada y actualiza la ventana.
   };
  };
  
  respuesta.onerror=function(e){
   alert(respuesta.error.name+"\n\n"+respuesta.error.message);
  };
  
  respuesta.oncomplete=function (e){
   alert("object successfully added");
  }; 
  
 };
 
 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}     

};
```

Se que el código no esta muy limpio y estructurado pero aun me falta practica.

Espero podáis ayudarme.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te pido por favor que introduzcas código en tu pregunta para poder responderte con una buena solución, si no tendré que pedir el cierre de la pregunta hasta que lo añadas. Gracias y suerte.

Comment: gracias por avisarme. ya he añadido el codigo afectado. saludos

Comment: @pablo Por favor, ¡indenta tu código correctamente! Si mezclas tabuladores y espacios, tarde o temprano tendrás problemas para leerlo bien.

Comment: indexdb no está pensado para guardar imagenes, porque no usas un campo que guarde la ruta de la imagen, y la imagen la guardas fisicamente al dispositivo, existen memoria cache, interna, externa etc..

Answer (score 2):

> por cada imagen que almaceno, los datos almacenados aumentan 10MB(por ejemplo), cuando la imagen solo ocupa 1MB

Primero: no estás almacenando imágenes, sino que estás almacenando la representación en base64 de la imagen, a través de una [URI `data:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs), porque haces:

`reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);`

Eso te va a [añadir un 37% de overhead](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/8334), así, para empezar.

> pero he revisado en ‘ajustes-aplicacion-app.instalada’, para ver cuanto ocupa

Estás confundiendo el tamaño de *la base de datos* con el tamaño de *los datos*.

> mas teniendo en cuenta que después de asignar imagen a cada elemento, lo que hago es reemplazar las imágenes, no añadir.

¿Estás totalmente seguro de que las versiones antiguas de las imágenes están desapareciendo de la BDD? IndexedDB es una base de datos transaccional y versionada, y es perfectamente factible que internamente se mantengan copias de las versiones antiguas de la BDD.

¡¡Usa las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador para inspeccionar los contenidos de la BDD!!

> después de seleccionar la imagen, la ‘pinta’ bastante rápido, pero después, en el proceso de almacenarla y recuperarla, va muy lento.

Normal. [El acceso a disco siempre va a ser más lento que el acceso a memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerarqu%C3%ADa_de_memoria).

Comment: gracias por las aclaraciones, me dan base para seguir aprendiendo. con respecto a si desaparecen las imágenes, lo he comprobado con las herramientas de desarrollado del chrome, e inspecciono la base de datos en la pestaña 'resource'. y solo hay una imagen por elemento, y el numero de elementos no aumenta.