# Como subir imagenes a nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, ecmascript-2015

Quiero subir varias imágenes a mi servidor nodejs que tienen información adicional como **titulo** y **categoría**, traté enviando las imagenes en **DataUrl** pero debido a las limitaciones de POST no me permite cargar mas de 2 imágenes por vez.

Para cargar las imágenes utilizo este componente de reactjs [Componente para cargar imágenes](https://codepen.io/edwin4312/pen/KmmEWm) que tiene el método **handleSubmitImages** para enviar el estado del componente al servidor mediante ajax.

***handleSubmitImages()***

```
handleSubmitImages(){
 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
 let json = JSON.stringify({images: this.state.images})
 xhr.open("POST",'new',true)
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
 xhr.send(json)
}
```

***Estado del componente***

El estado el componente esta formado por un array de objetos json que contienen la información de las imágenes así:

```
[ 
 { title: 'Imagen 264',
  file: [Blob], // Este es el blob del archivo
  data: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA', //Imagen en base64
  category: 1 } 
]
```

En el servidor tengo la ruta **wallpapers/new** para subir imágenes mediante el método **POST**.

***Ruta wallpapers/new***

```
router.route("/new")
  .get(function(req,res){
    res.render('wallpaper/new',{
      user: req.user
    })
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    let images = req.body.images
    images.map(image => {
     // Aquí debería poder guardar la imagen en mi servidor
    })
  });
```

**NOTA:** He leído tutoriales que hacen uso de **formidable** y **FormData()** para subir varias imágenes a la vez pero en ninguno de ellos envían información adicional como el titulo de la imagen o algo similar. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: y cual es el problema? no llegan los datos al `post`?

Comment: El blob del archivo llega vacio y el dataurl es demasiado largo para que se pueda enviar mas de 2 imágenes por vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario enviar la imagen 2 veces, te recomiendo que envies solamente el `data url` y te olvides de enviar Blob, no lo puedes serializar en un json, si elijes este camino, (hasta donde se) solo puede usar `FromData` el cual es un [metodo alternativo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394483/how-to-serialize-a-blob-javascript).

Para enviar multiples imágenes, puedes resolverlo muy facilmente moviendo el loop al lado del cliente. Asi el limite de transferencia del servidor se aplicara a cada imagen ([menos ~1/3 de overhead](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8346/25)) y no a toda la coleccion de imagenes. Ademas aprovechas mejor el ancho de banda por enviar varias imagenes a la vez.

```
handleSubmitImages(){
  // el loop lo haces aqui.
  this.state.images.forEach((image) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    let json = JSON.stringify({image})
    xhr.open("POST",'new',true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
    xhr.send(json)

    // TODO: manejar los errores de transferencia (retry policy/notification)
  }
}
```

Luego en server side solo recibes de a uno los archivos:

```
const fs = require('fs');

...

.post(function(req, res) {
    let image = req.body.image

    // luego extraes la cabecera del data url
    var base64Data = image.data.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, "");

    // grabas la imagen el disco
    fs.writeFile('nombredearchivo.jpg', base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    console.log(image.title); // Imagen 264
});
```